# http_ssl_module failed to install when compile from source code of nginx

Tags: nginx, openssl, certbot

I am trying to setup my https using certbot , so I need to recompile ngx adding '--with-http_ssl_module', here is the complete steps：

```
 - sudo make clean  sudo  
 - ./auto/configure --prefix=/var/www/html
   --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf- path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log
       --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --with-pcre --with-http_ssl_module  --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/etc/nginx/modules 
 - check Makefile , I can see 'http_ssl_module' added in objs/Makefile
 - ./auto/configure sudo make sudo make install
```

After completed all steps above(no error observed) I checked 'ngx_modules.o'(still missing ssl module) and ran command below

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d feedme.pub 
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log 
The nginx plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration. 
The error was: PluginError('Nginx build is missing SSL module (--with-http_ssl_module).')
```

Also , I checked my ssl lib- libssl is intalled:

```
ldconfig -p | grep libssl
    libssl3.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl3.so
    libssl.so.1.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
    libssl.so.1.0.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
    libssl.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
```

Anyone can help to answer why I am not able to build '--with-http_ssl_module' in ?

Comment: Why are you compiling nginx from source code?!

Comment: You probably want to stick to the compile options your distribution uses.. who knows what else is different.